# Error while running phonegap application. Any idea?

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova

Hi I was successfully created my first phonegap application by running

`$ phonegap create percentage`

Now i want to run it. So I run this command:

`phonegap run android`

However it throw me this error:
http://pastie.org/9076710

Anyone have idea about this?

Thank you

Comment: if you type `ant` on a terminal, do you get "command not found"?

Comment: which OS you use? windows or mac?

Comment: @LorenzoS I have not install ant yet. I'll be back  Dato: Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Install ant using brew.

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.